# Polymorphic Performance Hit

Tags: c#, performance, generics, polymorphism

I'm modelling some classes to represents units of measure in C#. For example, I have Millimeters and Inches modelled, with a `IDistanceUnit` interface and a base `DistanceUnit` class providing common implementation details.

There are basic arithmetic functions, defined as such, in each of the concrete classes:

```
public class Inches : 
    DistanceUnit<Inches>, 
    IDistanceUnit, 
    INumericUnit<Inches, IDistanceUnit>
{
    // ... snip ...
    public Inches Add(IDistanceUnit unit)
    {
        return new Inches(Value + unit.ToInches().Value);
    }
    // ... snip ...
}
```

Benchmarking 10,000,000 additions of different values converted to Inches and Millimeters has a small *but acceptable* performance hit. Raw doubles performing the conversion manually takes about 70-100ms, where the classes take about 700-1000ms.

I can abstract the details down into the `DistanceUnit` base class and remove some unnecessary duplication:

```
public abstract class DistanceUnit<TConcrete>
        IDistanceUnit,
        INumericUnit<TConcrete, IDistanceUnit>
    where TConcrete :
        IDistanceUnit,
        INumericUnit<TConcrete, IDistanceUnit>,
        new()
{
    // ... snip ...
    public TConcrete Add(IDistanceUnit unit)
    {
        TConcrete result = new TConcrete();
        reuslt.Value = Value + ToThis(unit).Value();
        return result;
    } 
    // ... snip ...
}
// ToThis() calls the correct "ToXYZ()" for the current implementing class
```

This drops my performance by *at least another factor of 10*. I'm seeing around 8000ms, just from moving the implementation into the base class, compared to 800ms.

**I've ruled out a few things from manual testing:**

- The switch to using `ToThis(IDistanceUnit)` shows no noticeable
  performance hit when used in the concrete class instead of the direct
  call to "ToInches" or "ToMillimeters"
- Creating the object with a parameterless constructor ( `new TConcrete()` ) and assigning 
  the value later has at worst a couple milliseconds of performance hit over 10,000,000 
  calculations.

I'm using the following code to benchmark my results:

```
int size = 10000000;
double[] mms = new double[size];
double[] inches = new double[size];

// Fill in some arbitrary test values
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    mms[i] = i;
    inches[i] = i;
}

Benchmark("Manual Conversion", () =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        var result = mms[i] + (inches[i] * 25.4);
    }
});

Benchmark("Unit Classes", () => 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        var result = (new Millimeters(mms[i])) + (new Inches(inches[i]));
    }
}
```

Where Benchmark just calls a stopwatch around the provided Action and prints out the time elapsed in milliseconds.

The only thing that appears to be causing a major difference is the movement of the `Add` function from the concrete classes to the abstract base class, but I don't understand why I would have a nearly 10x performance drop from just that. **Can anybody explain this to me** (and if possible, suggest a way to get a better speed without resorting to code duplication)?

Comment: I don't know C#, but if I had to guess, it looks like the polymorphic call is not being inlined.

Comment: @Mystical Aww man, I hope that's not the case. Just did a quick check, inline functions (outside of what the compiler does on its own) are only in 4.5 and above, and I'm stuck in 4.0 and below.

Comment: The JIT compiler could always inline functions, that's not new to 4.5 - only the ability to request aggressive inlining is new.

Comment: For better understanding why you have performance issue overall, it's better to know implementation details of ToInches() method, or ToThis() method. Also, what type is Value property? Give more details.

Comment: I was actually thinking on a slightly broader scope. Polymorphic calls usually *cannot* be inlined unless the type can be determined at compile time...for C/C++ at least. I'm not sure about JIT'ed languages, but I'd assume a similar restriction.

Comment: About the base class: the new() constraint of the type class is slow, creating the object with "new T()" generates Activator.CreateInstance<T>() code, which is slow. It should be the main reason of your second performance hit, not because of moving code to base class.

Comment: @anderhil I didn't know that. It sounds a likely cause. Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: yes, but i'm still insterested in why you have 10 times perfomance hit comparing to pure double calculations, only with this it will be  complete answer. Also, firstly give a try and substitute new T() with some exact instantiation code.

Comment: @anderhil The performance hit is likely because the class is generally treated as immutable, and there are a lot of object creations going on compared to using primitive doubles. The "Value" property is a simple double, but any addition of two `Unit` types will create a new one (the same way 1+2 creates a new value, 3, instead of mutating one or the other).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first perfomance hit as i said in comments, I need to know some implementation details:
ToInches() method, ToThis() method, the type or code of Value property.

For the second perfomance hit, the most likely reason is the you use new() constrain for base class and use 
`TConcrete result = new TConcrete();`

Compiler generates `Activator.CreateInstance<TConcrete>()` in this case, this method uses reflection under the hood and is slow. In case you have millions of instantiations it will decrease performance for sure. [Here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/08/22/optimization-and-generics-part-1-the-new-constraint.aspx) you can find some benchmarks from Jon Skeet.

If you use >= 3.5 framework you can use expression trees to build fast generic instantiation of objects in your base class:

```
private static Func<TConcrete> _createFunc;

    private static TConcrete CreateNew()
    {
            if (_func == null)
            {
                _createFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<TConcrete>>(Expression.New(typeof (TConcrete))).Compile();
            }
            return _createFunc.Invoke();
    }

    public TConcrete Add(IDistanceUnit unit)
    {
            TConcrete result = CreateNew();
            result.Value = Value + ToThis(unit).Value();
            return result;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck supporting stuff as low as .NET 2.0, but the revelation as to the fact that `new()` uses `Activator.CreateInstance` is a really helpful one. Thanks.